# Join part of line in csv with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have one csv file like this:

```
"Name","surname","note"
"Jhon","Jhon","fdskngkfngkfnkglnlksanjlbgsjangkjlvnkajsdf"
"Jhon2","Jhon2","fdssfsfsfkngkfngkfnkglnlksanjlbgsjangkjlvnkajsdf"
"Jhon3","Jhon3","fdssfsfsfkngkfngkfnk
glnlksanjlbgsjangkjlvnkajsdf"
"Jhon4","Jhon4","fdssfsfsf
kngkfngkfnkglnlks
anjlbgsjangkjlvnkajsdf"
```

I need to join the line who return, because i need to add this file in mySQL.

I use this code

```
$csv_file = "output.csv";
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;

while (!feof($csvfile))
{
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode('","', $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();

    $insert_csv['Gestore'] = ltrim($csv_array[0], '"'); 

   echo $insert_csv['Gestore'] . "</br>";
   $query = "INSERT INTO prova(Gestore) VALUES('".$insert_csv['Gestore']."')";
   $n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
   $i++;
}
```

It works but i need to solve precedent problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the PHP function [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

As an alternative to PHP you could use

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
```

see [MySQL manual, LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html), if you've got the `FILE` privilege.